# PTY gem not found

Tags: ruby, rubygems, pty

I have Ruby 1.9.3 installed on windows. When I try to require the gem the console outputs that the gem was not found:

```
require 'pty'
```

Which outputs:

```
'require': cannot load such file -- pty <LoadError>
```

Also I tried:

```
gem install pty
```

And got this output:

```
Could not find a valid gem 'pty' in any repository
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no PTY module implementation for Windows as they don't have pseudo-terminal capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
gem install rubysl-pty
```

if target ruby version is 1.9.x, run gem command with appropriate -v option

```
gem install rubysl-pty -v 1.0.0
```

if you would like to use PTY on Windows, my best recommendation is to use cygwin. I am able to install and use this rubysl-pty on my Windows with cygwin yet with few limitations:

```
$ gem install rubysl-pty -v 1.0.0
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rubysl-pty-1.0.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rubysl-pty-1.0.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for rubysl-pty-1.0.0...
```

Sample code:

```
# test.rb
require 'pty'
PTY.getpty("ls") { |i,o,pid| p i; p pid }
```

Output:

```
$ ruby test.rb
#<File:/dev/pty0>
16376
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently seems ruby is supporting 'pty' module out of the box so you don't have to install any gem: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html