# Detecting when a subprocess expects input in Ruby

Tags: ruby, io

I have a console application (command response type) that I want to control its IO so I can feed it with a script from file and then continue the execution manually when the script execution is finished.

my script is this:

```
ARGF.readlines = commands

IO.popen('ConsoleApplication') { |io|
    begin
        puts io.gets
        sleep 0.1
    end while ????
}
```

As I observed IO.popen connects the input of io object to the process IO but the output should be read. If by some means the output was displayed automatically or I could detect when the process is waiting for input where ???? is I think I could consider this matter as done!

Comment: https://github.com/abates/ruby_expect

Comment: by first look it seems to be exactly relative. Thanks. But, was it really this hard!! I mean I expected from a language like ruby to do these jobs much more simple

Comment: I'm working on ruby_expect and was trying to have a simple test with PTY but I get error when on >require "pty"<. Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467182/pty-gem-not-found) true that I can't use PTY on windows. If that is the case then I can't use ruby_expect either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My further workaround results:
Expect do not work on widows because windows do not support pseudo terminals(PTY) so I can't use ruby_expect like libraries for windows!

I tried IO.select in combination with IO.read_nonblock which encounters "bad file pointer". Some people said that [non-blocking IO is not supported in windows as well](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3554151)

So I used some special strings to synchronize the read-write sequences myself and the task is done.