# Ruby Web-console 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I've been going through the update rails tutorial and came across this error with the web console. I attempted reinstalling the bundles with no avail. Any input? This was the error i recieved:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console/slave.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- pty (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console/slave.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console.rb:13:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from C:/Users/lmiln/workspace/toy_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in `generate_or_destroy'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:50:in `generate'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: have you tried searching for the similar question?

Comment: eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467182/pty-gem-not-found  The problem is that the gem is trying to "shell out" to a command "pty", which is not available in Windows.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426280/what-do-pty-and-tty-mean